# What does CWM back up?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, nandroid

I made a backup using ClockworkMod Recovery v6.0.4.7d of my Samsung I9305 (it runs a rooted stock Android 4.4.4). I selected "Backup and restore" and then "Backup to /storage/sdcard1". The resulting image was of about 7GB.

Does this backup contain:

1. The firmware?
2. My modifications to the firmware such as root, Xposed Framework, installed Xposed modules, etc.?
3. My installed apps?
4. App data?
5. Other data I had stored on the internal SD card?

And finally, is compression utilized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to: https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/ClockWorkMod_Instructions#Making_a_backup

> ClockworkMod's backup/restore feature will generally only back up the
>   `/system`, `/data`, `/cache`, `/sd-ext`, and `/dalvik-cache` areas. Other
>   partitions such as `/emmc`, `/sdcard`, and `/media` won't be backed up.
>
> In
>   fact, the backed up system will typically be saved to the `/sdcard/`
>   partition in the `/clockworkmod/backup/` directory, which, depending on
>   your device, may or may not be actually located on a physical
>   removable SD card.

According to your question:

> 1. The firmware?

Definitely Yes.

> 2. My modifications to the firmware such as root, Xposed Framwork, installed Xposed modules, etc?

Definitely Yes.

> 3. My installed apps?

Definitely Yes.

> 4. App data?

Definitely Yes.

> 5. Other data I had stored on the internal SD card?

Definitely NO, `/sdcard` is not backed up, because of there would be a CWM backup. Read: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/help/how-to-backup-internal-sdcard-t1999853

Hope it help

Answer (score 6):

To add to other answer, your back up has ALL the information in your back up image as the phone has when you took back up

- `/system` refers to your ROM
- `/data` refers to your data created by apps both that came with phone and user installed apps (`/data/data`)
- `/data/cache` (the cache) refers to app data stored for quick access
- `/data/dalvik-cache` (the Dalvik cache) refers to storage where optimisation information of your apps is stored
- `/sd-ext` refers to external SD card (all CWMs do not by default save this)

Other partitions mentioned are not backed up. Compression happens if you enable it (IMO, not worth the extra time it takes, given you can always store it in external SD (by choosing it) or pull it to your PC)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Would upvote your answer but my reputation is too low.

Comment: There's also the `/sdcard` or the `/flash` partitions, which point to the internal memory of the device. My tablet and phone (Android 4.4.2) have an `/sdcard` mounted, which is the internal memory. My Old Android 2.1 tablet uses `/flash` instead. Also, for USB-OTG devices, `/usb` points to the USB external storage.